# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" when interacting with devnet

Tags: devnet, sugar

Hey so I am having an issue with deploying a test collection on devnet, getting this error:

```
Transaction error: error sending request for url (https://api.devnet.solana.com/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)
```

I also tried to update candy machine and verify it. Both trigger the same error, but update sometimes works (like 1 time out of 10)

Additionally, the same happens when I try solana airdrop command. Yesterday I could airdrop just fine.

Is it maybe fault with the devnet? too congested? Pls help

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the rpc you are using does not accept your connection.

Try a different rpc like devnet.genesysgo.net

Comment: perfect, works like a charm now